# Расчёт расстояния внутри полигона и снаружи отдельно?

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь рассчитать расстояние от фиксированных координат, у каждой координаты есть свой радиус, и если кликнули за пределами радиуса, то считало расстояние от фиксированной координаты до координаты клика, маршрут создается и полное расстояние я нахожу, но как найти расстояние до точки пересечения с радиусом? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так вычтите радиус

Comment: Получится не корректное расстояние, т.к маршрут строится не напрямую, а с изгибами.

Comment: Можно тупо перебрать все точки на окружности и проверять их цвет (это же canvas?). Как только он будет фиолетовым - найдена точка пересечения. Построить две новых дороги: От начальной точки до пересечения, и от пересечния до конца. Надо дополнительно обработать изогнутую дорогу, которая пересекает окружность дважды. Это всё при условии, что нет возможности разобраться, как изначально рисуется дорога, чтобы прямо в этих расчетах вносить изменения.

Comment: А как проверяются точки на окружности?